# Enviando dados com php/jquery para o mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia enviar os dados da tela index.php para o mysql , sendo que foi usado o javascript/jquery para fazer essa função que está sendo mostrada na imagem abaixo.

meus código estão abaixo :

O meu index

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="restaurant-title">Peixaria</h1>

    <div id="menu-panel" class="col-sm-12 paddingselect">
        <?php categoriaas(); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="menu-panel-2"></div>

    <div id="caja-panel">
        <div class="well">

            <!-- left -->
            <div id="theproducts" class="col-sm-5"></div>

            <!-- left -->
            <input type="text" id="theinputsum">

            <!-- right -->
            <div id="thetotal" class="col-sm-7">
                <h1 id="total"></h1>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                    Finalizar Pedido
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- right -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Restaurant -->
<script src="js/restaurant.js"></script>
```

O meu `processfunction`:

```php
require_once 'resfunctions.php';

if (isset($_POST['categoria'])) {
    getproductos($_POST['categoria']);
}
```

E outros que se eu colocar na pergunta vai ficar grande.
Fico grato desde já.

Comment: Leia sobre ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que você já está usando jQuery, utilize a função Ajax dele (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Você chama o arquivo PHP que vai inserir no MySQL, dá um retorno ao javascript e faz os demais procedimentos do javascript.

Um exemplo de utilização da função ajax

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: $("#iDdoForm").serialize()
})
  .done(function( retorno) {
    alert( "faça as ações necessárias de acordo com o retorno" );
  });
```

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJaraouch teria como me mostrar em código como fazer isso ?

Comment: Na edição do meu comentário, tem um exemplo de código, para o total entendimento do que você quer fazer você deverá ler sobre ajax.

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche o que seria esse $("#iDdoForm")

Comment: O  seletor do form(que você) vai enviar as informações, que vai ter um id, isso no html p.ex <form id="idDoForm" ...>